# Spring Data MongoDB with Java 8 LocalDate MappingException

Tags: spring, mongodb, date, spring-data

I try to use the LocalTime from Java 8 Date Time API with Spring Data MongoDB. Inserting the document works as expected, but when I try to read the document, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:637)
    ....
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No property null found on entity class java.time.LocalDate to bind constructor parameter to!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.java:63)
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:71)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:257)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:237)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1109)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$100(MappingMongoConverter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1058)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getValueInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:789)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:270)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:263)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:261)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:263)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:237)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDbObjectCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:2005)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1699)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1522)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1506)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:532)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:217)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:174)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:358)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at hello.Application.run(Application.java:36)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:634)
    ... 5 more
```

I tried this with the example from the Spring website: http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/
I just changed to Customer to have a birthdate:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Customer {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private LocalDate birthDay;

    public Customer() {}

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, LocalDate birthDay) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.birthDay = birthDay;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Customer[id=%s, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
                id, firstName, lastName);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wrote this little bit of code for all 4 of these conversion options:

- DateToLocalDateTimeConverter
- DateToLocalDateConverter
- LocalDateTimeToDateConverter
- LocalDateToDateConverter

Here is an example

```
public class DateToLocalDateTimeConverter implements Converter<Date, LocalDateTime> {

    @Override 
    public LocalDateTime convert(Date source) { 
        return source == null ? null : LocalDateTime.ofInstant(source.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault()); 
    }
}
```

All example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-date-to-localdate-and-localdatetime).

Then by including this in the xml configuration for the mongodb connection I was able to work in java 8 dates with mongodb (remember to add all the converters):

```
<mongo:mapping-converter>
    <mongo:custom-converters>
        <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="package.DateToLocalDateTimeConverter" />
        </mongo:converter>
    </mongo:custom-converters>
</mongo:mapping-converter>
```

Comment: Good one! There will be an out-of-the box implementation for that in the upcoming [1.7 M1](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1102).

Comment: @OliverGierke I tried to use http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/org/springframework/data/spring-data-mongodb/1.7.0.M1/ and i still get "No property null found on entity class java.time.LocalDateTime to bind constructor parameter to"

Comment: I am still facing this issue.. Any help other than defining our own custom converters?

Answer (score 3):

Now problem is resolved:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1102

But Spring Data doesn't support ZonedDateTime now, only Local.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported mostly due to the fact that MongoDB doesn't support storing Java 8 date time types right now. I suggest to turn the internal property into a legacy `Date` one and do the conversions on the API of the domain class (as you would do with Hibernate and JodaTime e.g.).