# Cannot serialize LocalDate in Mongodb

Tags: java, json, mongodb, scala

I am using the java 8 java.time.LocalDate to parse around dates.

But trying to insert a LocalDate object to mongodb. I get errors in the java driver:

```
private def writeData(measure: DBCollection, installation: Int, date: String, dates: ListBuffer[LocalDate],
                    values: ListBuffer[BigDecimal], validated: Boolean, overwrite: Boolean) {
  val timeValues: BasicDBList = new BasicDBList
  var i = 0
  while ( i < dates.size )  {
    val obj: BasicDBObject = new BasicDBObject("time", dates(i))
    obj.put("value", values(i).toString())
    timeValues.add(obj)
    i += 1
  }
  if ( debug ) System.out.println("Storedata: " + timeValues.toString) <-- error here
```

Errorlog:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: json can't serialize type : class java.time.LocalDate
>       at com.mongodb.util.ClassMapBasedObjectSerializer.serialize(ClassMapBasedObjectSerializer.java:77)
>       at com.mongodb.util.JSONSerializers$MapSerializer.serialize(JSONSerializers.java:317)
>       at com.mongodb.util.ClassMapBasedObjectSerializer.serialize(ClassMapBasedObjectSerializer.java:79)
>       at com.mongodb.util.JSONSerializers$IterableSerializer.serialize(JSONSerializers.java:290)
>       at com.mongodb.util.ClassMapBasedObjectSerializer.serialize(ClassMapBasedObjectSerializer.java:79)
>       at com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize(JSON.java:54)
>       at com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize(JSON.java:40)
>       at com.mongodb.BasicDBList.toString(BasicDBList.java:38)
>       at web.MeasureAccess.writeData(MeasureAccess.scala:203)
>       at web.MeasureAccess.firstTime(MeasureAccess.scala:52)
>       at web.MeasureAccess$.main(MeasureAccess.scala:262)
>       at web.MeasureAccess.main(MeasureAccess.scala)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

I am using the mongo-java-driver-2.13.0-rc1.jar
Scala 2.11.4
and java 1.8.0_25

For completeness.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, the MongoDB driver uses the `java.util.Date` type, see the docs [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-types/)

So you have to convert your LocalDate to a Date instance first, for example:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("test");
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("testcol");

LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now();
Instant instant = ld.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
Date date = Date.from(instant);

BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("localdate", date);
coll.insert(doc);
```

I would suggest using something like [Morphia](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia) or [Jongo](http://jongo.org/) to wrap the MongoDB driver though, as you can register global mappers to implicitly do these conversions on the fly, so that you can use LocalDate, etc, in your domain model

Comment: Thank you for the reference on Morphia and Jongo. I will definitely look those up.

Comment: I should comment that at this point, with the 3.x drivers, I find the need for Morphia and Jongo are less relevant as it's much simpler to plug in custom serlializers with Jackson / Jackson4Bson for the few extra types you may need

Answer (score 5):

For anyone coming across this question, the following converter would get someone started in the right direction. This `TypeConverter` converts between `Date` and `LocalDateTime` (Making this distinction because the OP specifically asked about LocalDate).

Add the following converter to Morphia as follows:

```
morphia.getMapper().getConverters().addConverter(new LocalDateTimeConverter());
```

Here is the converter class:

```
public class LocalDateTimeConverter extends TypeConverter implements SimpleValueConverter {

    public LocalDateTimeConverter() {
        // TODO: Add other date/time supported classes here
        // Other java.time classes: LocalDate.class, LocalTime.class
        // Arrays: LocalDateTime[].class, etc
        super(LocalDateTime.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object decode(Class<?> targetClass, Object fromDBObject, MappedField optionalExtraInfo) {
        if (fromDBObject == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (fromDBObject instanceof Date) {
            return ((Date) fromDBObject).toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
        }

        if (fromDBObject instanceof LocalDateTime) {
            return fromDBObject;
        }

        // TODO: decode other types

        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Cannot decode object of class: %s", fromDBObject.getClass().getName()));
    }

    @Override
    public Object encode(Object value, MappedField optionalExtraInfo) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (value instanceof Date) {
            return value;
        }

        if (value instanceof LocalDateTime) {
            ZonedDateTime zoned = ((LocalDateTime) value).atZone(ZoneOffset.systemDefault());
            return Date.from(zoned.toInstant());
        }

        // TODO: encode other types

        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Cannot encode object of class: %s", value.getClass().getName()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[As Oliver Gierke mentions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22980626/1673576)

This datatype is not supported yet. I hope this will be available soon.