# Java Mongo search by LocalDate

Tags: java, mongodb, localdate

is any easy solution how to find date in Mongo DB by LocalDate (ex. findByLocaDate method)? in Mongo it is saved like UTC format and String parsing is not what Im looking for, any clever solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot serialize LocalDate in Mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799952/cannot-serialize-localdate-in-mongodb)

Comment: Im looking for easy solution findBy.... its possible with spring data? without any boiler code Convertor?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/convert/threeten/Jsr310JpaConverters.html) helps then?

Comment: thats not what im looking for but thanks