# "MappingException: No property null found on entity class java.time.OffsetDateTime to bind constructor parameter to!" with Spring MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, java-time

Trying to use the new `java.time.OffsetDateTime` object with MongoDB. I'm using `org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.8.2.RELEASE`. It seems to be able to write to the DB fine, but when I try to read the data, it throws the below exception. If I instead change my object to just `LocalDateTime`, it is able to read/write to the DB successfully. Is there additional configuration I need to do to add support for the OffsetDateTime object?

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No property null found on entity class java.time.OffsetDateTime to bind constructor parameter to!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.java:74) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:71) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:83) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:251) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:231) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1186) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$200(MappingMongoConverter.java:78) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1134) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getValueInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:870) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:283) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:271) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:309) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:271) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:231) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22972679/spring-data-mongodb-with-java-8-localdate-mappingexception. Looks like the issue was fixes for `LocalDateTime`, but may be not for `OffsetDateTime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems the current JSR-310 support only works with non-time-zoned date objects. That would explain why OffsetDateTime was not working.

https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/26/what-s-new-in-spring-data-fowler

> This setup will make sure that both your application package and the
>   Spring Data JPA one for the JSR-310 converters will be scanned and
>   handed to the persistence provider. Find a complete example for that
>   in our Spring Data Examples repository. Note, that due to the fact
>   that the converter simply converts the JSR-310 types to legacy Date
>   instances, only non-time-zoned (e.g. LocalDateTime etc.) are
>   supported.

I was able to work-around this by falling back to using the Joda DateTime object. I had to do the following:

1. Add `compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.6.3')` to gradle.build file.
2. Add `spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=false` to application.properties file to make the outputs human-readable.
3. `import org.joda.time.DateTime;` and use this instead of OffsetDateTime