# MongoRepository query for between dates

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

My pojo

```
public class PacketData implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private final String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    private final ZonedDateTime arrived = ZonedDateTime.now();
}
```

I plan to use like following.

```
@Query("?")
List<PacketData> findPacketArrivedBetween(ZonedDateTime startDate, ZonedDateTime endDate);
```

Is there a way i can put the following query to the above `query` annotation and how i can do greater than and less than logic

```
Query query = new Query().addCriteria(Criteria.where("arrived").gte(startDate).lte(endDate));
```

Comment: Spring Data MongoDB has no built-in support for `ZonedDateTime`, only `LocalDateTime`. Using `ZonedDateTime` requires a [custom converter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-explicit-converters) to persist the timezone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try following couple of ways.

Without Query Annotation.

```
List<PacketData> findByArrivedBetween(ZonedDateTime startDate, ZonedDateTime endDate);
```

With Query Annotation.

```
@Query("{'arrived': {$gte: ?0, $lte:?1 }}")
List<PacketData> findPacketArrivedBetween(ZonedDateTime startDate, ZonedDateTime endDate);
```

Comment: This is not a valid answer as MongoRepository does not support ZonedDateTime: the MongoDB driver uses the java.util.Date type

Comment: @user666 the user was already using custom converter to accommodate ZonedDateTime. More here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41127665/zoneddatetime-with-mongodb/41146758#41146758

Comment: is there a way to send epoch timestamp in @query? for example in MongoDB compass we case use new Date([epoch integer]) and it works well. Is this posisble using spring boot jpa?

Comment: I tried this on Mongo 4.0.9 and the between using `@Query` annotation doesn't seem to work. But the query method technique works as expected. Any idea why?

Comment: I think it's the findByArrivedBetween is actually returning lt and gt strictly not or equal to.

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol '$gte' in idea