# MongoRepository query if date was within last week

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

how do i query mongodb to find out if a date in the database is within 1 week from today?

i tried stuff [MongoRepository query for between dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189770/mongorepository-query-for-between-dates) but i kept getting an error

Class

```
    POJO class {
    
        private String id;
    
        private String userId;
    
        private String userName;
    
        private String email;
    
        private Date changeDate;
    }
```

Mongo Repo

```
  public interface POJOREPO extends MongoRepository<POJO, String> {

    POJOCLASS findByUserIdAndFindTopByOrderByChangeDateDesc(String userId, Date todayDate);

}
```

I would like it to return either a boolean or the entity meaning the date is within a week from the current date

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: What do you mean by "within 1 week from today"? 7 days from today? Which day do you consider as the first day of the week?

Comment: @earandap i just checked again org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: No property findTopBy found for type.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit so if a user makes changes to their account today i want it to be they cant make any changes for a week or a specified period and for that i have to check the last date they made changes and see if its been less than a week from the current day they try to make another change