# How to implement a MongoDB codec for ZoneRegion

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, java-time, bson

I'm trying to store a field of type `java.time.ZoneId` in MongoDB. For this type, I require an `org.bson.codecs.Codec` which I do have. However, when I try to insert the `ZoneId` it gives the following:

`Can't find a codec for class java.time.ZoneRegion`

This is where this block of code comes in:

```
package java.time
static ZoneId of(String zoneId, boolean checkAvailable) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(zoneId, "zoneId");
        if (zoneId.length() <= 1 || zoneId.startsWith("+") || zoneId.startsWith("-")) {
            return ZoneOffset.of(zoneId);
        } else if (zoneId.startsWith("UTC") || zoneId.startsWith("GMT")) {
            return ofWithPrefix(zoneId, 3, checkAvailable);
        } else if (zoneId.startsWith("UT")) {
            return ofWithPrefix(zoneId, 2, checkAvailable);
        }
        return ZoneRegion.ofId(zoneId, checkAvailable);
    }
```

It is creating a `ZoneRegion` for my case `ZoneId.of("Africa/Harare")`.
`ZoneRegion` is private which is causing problems for me as I now can't create a codec for it:

`final class ZoneRegion extends ZoneId implements Serializable`

```
println(ZoneId.of("Africa/Harare").getClass)

class java.time.ZoneRegion
```

The question is. How do I implement a codec for `ZoneRegion`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a codec from a `ZoneOffset`?

Comment: Yes. For `ZoneId.of("+02:00")`, which results in a `ZoneOffset`, I'm able to insert it .

Comment: Would that be sufficient or does the problem persist?

Comment: For my use case I need to present, for example, `Africa/Harare` to the user. I can get the `ZoneOffset`(+02:00) but then I can't go back to the zone unfortunately as (+02:00) represents multiple locations.
The workaround for us currently is to have the field as `zoneId: String` which is not ideal.

Comment: Well, that seems to be kind of a difficult problem... [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41127665/zoneddatetime-with-mongodb) is a discussion about registering a codec/converter for `ZonedDateTime`, which is obviously the only main datetime class of `java.time` that is **not** supported by MongoDB.